# How to Display an image in a showLoader instead of type Boolen

Tags: javascript, angular, 360-panorama, photosphere, photosphereviewer

I want to display an image while is loading in Panorama in a photoSphereViewer instead of the text that is displayed when the showLoader is true
[image]

[setPanorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cJFc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIHgH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpeK7.png)

Comment: Which package are you using exactly? What do they say in their documentation with regard to the behavior you want to implement?

Comment: Next time, you should add the code directly (with copy paste) instead of an image. It's easier this way.

Comment: Did you had a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mistic100/5r684etx/) with the exact loading image config that you need?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thank you for your reply , i want a loading img when i change from sweep to another sweep so i used the type PanoramaOptions that i founded in a photoSphereViewer and there is a parametere `panoData?: PanoData | PanoDataProvider`  that function to compute panorama data once the image is loaded [Search for a  PSV.PanoDataProvide] (https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/api/psv) , but i didnt know how to pass an image to panoData in a PanoramaOptions

Comment: Is it using the same `Viewer` instance? If so, then you should be able to configure the `loadingImg` url like in the fiddle I linked earlier.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu no but i should pass by the ` PanoramaOptions` in the package photoSphereViewer and in the PanoramaOptions there is a `panoData?: PanoData | PanoDataProvider` with too types and for this case i want to use `type PanoDataProvider = (image: HTMLImageElement) => PanoData;` but i didnt know how to pass an image to panoData

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu i updated the post , look at it maybe you will understand more

Comment: You still need to create a `Viewer` in order to call the `.setPanorama` method on it. That takes an options parameter on the constructor where you can specify the URI of the image using the `loadingImg` property. In other words, don't try to set the image on the `PanoData` or `PanoDataProvider` because there won't be any property that allows you to do it there. You can only decide if you want to show the loader or not (using the `showLoader` property).

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2omdeyu/). I left some comments there which I hope can clarify things a bit.

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots, instead post the actual code

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thanks a lot , it helped me too much , but know I have a little problem that not all the photos that displayed .